# Include a reference in the bibliography without citing it in the text

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

This might be a silly question, but I want to include a reference without actually citing it in the article, I just want it to be added to references.

I'm using a .bib file which is included in the .tex file, and the entry is a standard entry like:

```
@misc{xyz,
    author = "NAME",
    date = "YEAR",
    howpublished = "personal communication"
    }
```

Comment: `\nocite{xyz} `

Comment: Whether you use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or BibTeX, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `\nocite{keyname}` for a single input in the references without marking it in the document. To mark any key in the `.bib` file use `\nocite{*}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{mysuperbib.bib}
@misc{xyz,
    author = "A.N.{A}uthor",
    date = "2525",
    howpublished = "personal communication"
    }
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\nocite{xyz}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mysuperbib}

\end{document}
```