# Can I include alll .bib file entries into text, even if references are missing from main text?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have written my thesis using Overleaf and managed references using `biblatex` - all worked fine.

Now I have to make a 15-20 page-long "executive summary" with virtually no equations nor references in this second text. At the end of this "executive summary", I have to provide a "List of main literature used in the thesis".

Is there a way to do this automatically from my original .bib file, using some arguments to the

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}`
or 
`\printbibliography` commands?

I am aware of the "manual" option available through
`\begin{thebibliography}` `\end{thebibliography}` but I hope there is a simpler way.

I have already searched this site and `biblatex` package reference pdf, with no success.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Probably you are interested in the `\nocite` command. You can either use `\nocite{*}` to include all references of a `.bib` file or `\nocite{<key>}`(See page 110 of the `biblatex` documentation).

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works. Sorry I cannot mark your comment as answer solving my question..... I was searching the `biblatex` documentation for wrong keywords.

Comment: Instead of writing up an answer, I'd suggest to close your question as a duplicate to  one of the following: [Include a reference in the bibliography without citing it in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269136/134144) or [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/134144) Would you agree?

Comment: OK, I agree, thank you. (I don't have the priviledges to do this).